# クロスコンパイル中のdpkg-buildpackage: error

Tags: linux, ubuntu, raspberry-pi

どうすれば下記のエラーが解消できますでしょうか？
よろしくお願いいたします。

**起きているエラー:**

```
$ time make -j 1 ARCH=arm64 CROSS_COMPILE=aarch64-linux-gnu- LOCALVERSION="-cfs-raspi" -j$(nproc) deb-pkg

  CC [M]  fs/btrfs/discard.o
  CC [M]  fs/btrfs/reflink.o
  CC [M]  fs/btrfs/subpage.o
  CC [M]  fs/btrfs/tree-mod-log.o
  CC [M]  fs/btrfs/acl.o
  LD [M]  fs/btrfs/btrfs.o
make[2]: *** [debian/rules:7: build-arch] Error 2
dpkg-buildpackage: error: debian/rules binary subprocess returned exit status 2
make[1]: *** [scripts/Makefile.package:77: deb-pkg] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:1554: deb-pkg] Error 2
```

#### やったこと

`-lelf -lz` が無いとのことでしたので、以下二つのパッケージを入れてみましたが、同じエラーが出てきます。
`SYSTEM_TRUSTED_KEYS` のコメントアウトもしています。

`apt search libelf` で出てきた、

libelfin-dev/jammy,now 0.3-2.1 amd64 [installed]
C++11 ELF/DWARF parser (development files)

`apt search libz`

genwqe-tools/jammy,now 4.0.18-3.1 amd64 [installed]
utilities for accelerated libz implementation

**実行環境:**

```
cat /proc/version
Linux version 5.15.0-91-generic (buildd@lcy02-amd64-045) (gcc (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.38) #101-Ubuntu SMP Tue Nov 14 13:30:08 UTC 2023
```

クロスコンパイルの参考にしているページ:
[Build Linux Kernel Image for Raspberry Pi from Source [Ubuntu Server]](https://hackmd.io/@henrybear327/Bkcq9h3-K)

Comment: エラーメッセージは省略せずに全て載せてください。また、エラーメッセージだけでなく実行したコマンド等も同様に記載してください。

Comment: 「-lelf -lz が無いとのこと」とありますが、該当するエラーメッセージが見当りません。編集履歴を見ると、最初は有ったのかも知れません。cubickさんのコメントにもありますが、エラーメッセージは省略しない方がよいです。あまりに長すぎて削っている場合は、その旨記載して下さい。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

クロスコンパイル+クロスリンクしたい、ってことですから、その `libelf.a` や `libz.a` は（あるいは共用ライブラリは）

- `amd64` 版つまり `Linux amd64` 用のものではなくて
- `Raspberry pi` 用クロスライブラリつまりは `aarch64-linux-gnu` 版
が必要です。

> `libelfin-dev/jammy,now 0.3-2.1 amd64 [installed]`
> `genwqe-tools/jammy,now 4.0.18-3.1 amd64 [installed]`

というメッセージからは `Linux amd64` 版が入っていることは確認できます。
が、これだけでは `raspberry pi` 用 `aarch64-linux-gnu` 版が入っているかどうかは不明です。

`aarch64` 用にコンパイル済みのライブラリファイルを探すか
`aarch64` 用に自分でクロスコンパイルして構築してください。

Answer (score 0):

"`-lelf -lz` が無い" に対してインストールすべきパッケージは [libelf-dev](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/libelf-dev) , [zlib1g-dev](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/zlib1g-dev) だと思います。

amd64 の実行環境で RasPi (arm64) 向けのパッケージをインストールする場合には、以下の様にパッケージ名に続けてアーキテクチャを指定するようです。

```
$ sudo apt install libelf-dev:arm64 zlib1g-dev:arm64
```

Comment: それでフツーにインストールされるのは `amd64` 版だと思うのですが。

Comment: 回答に情報を追記しました。